# QML: flat non-scrollable list view

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to have two list views followed by one another in a big ScrollView, say because they have slightly different delegates. So a layout is like this:

[image: Layout with two list views in a scroll view]]

Unfortunately ListView type is also a flickable, so it doesn't present all its content in a flat list suitable for having inside a scroll view. 
So how do I do this with Qt Quick views?

I've tried a trick: I can resize list views like this:

```
    ListView {
        id: list1

        height: contentHeight + spacing * count

        model: superModel
        delegate: delegate1
    }
```

Unfortunately, aside from being a dirty hack and leaving an unneccesary flickable grabbing my clicks, it doesn't really work: content just doesn't fit as there are still top and bottom margins I don't know the value of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ColumnLayout` with two `Repeater`'s in a `ScrollView` (or `Flickable` if you like)

```
ScrollView {
    contentWidth: width   //maybe you don't need this

    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width   //maybe you don't need this

        Repeater {
            model: superModel1
            delegate: delegate1
        }

        Repeater {
            model: superModel2
            delegate: delegate2
        }
    }
}
```

Since you didn't show the delegate, you might need minor tweaking of `implicitHeight` and/or `implicitWidth`.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what i needed. Didn't even require any implicitHeight tweaks for now.